# How do I align summation signs instead of their subscripts?

Tags: align

I am trying to align a set of equations. However, I would like to align the summation symbols. Now, their subscripts are aligned, which results in the summation symbols being (or at least, looking) unaligned.

This is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
 &\sum_{j \in \mathcal{V}': (i,j) \in \mathcal{A}}x_{ij}^E &\le 1, && \forall i \in \mathcal{R}',\\
 &\sum_{i \in \mathcal{N}_E \backslash \mathcal{N}_{342}: (i,j) \in \mathcal{A}}x_{ij}^E &= 0 && j \in \mathcal{R}_s',
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

which results in the following:

[image]

I would like to see the summation **symbols** aligned. How do I do this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

In case the OP posted

Comment: Thank you, I edited the question. Hope this helps!

Comment: Simply remove the `&`s at the beginning of the lines.

Comment: See the `mathtools` package. You probably want `\smashoperator[l]{ ...}` around each `\sum` including the limits of the sum.

Comment: There is also \mathclap (mathtools) for just the arguments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `\smashopeorator[l]{...}` from `mathtools` for this.
Here I've aligned on the sums, the `\le,=` and the consitions, using `alignat` for better spacing.

Note also that I use `\setminus` not `\backslash`. `\setminus` has proper status (don't remember if it is a binary operation), whereas `\backslash` is a normal symbol (aka no automatic spacing).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{3}
  &\smashoperator[l]{\sum_{j \in \mathcal{V}': (i,j) \in \mathcal{A}}}
  x_{ij}^E &\le 1, &\qquad& \forall i \in \mathcal{R}',\\
 &\smashoperator[l]{\sum_{i \in \mathcal{N}_E \setminus
     \mathcal{N}_{342}: (i,j) \in \mathcal{A}}}
 x_{ij}^E &= 0 && j \in \mathcal{R}_s',
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

I would avoid so long subscripts, breaking them into two lines.

You can get the alignment with the help of `eqparbox`; the first argument to `\mathbox` is a unique identifier, which must be different for every usage.

I'd also use `alignat`, in order to avoid excessive space between the equation and the related condition.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{eqparbox}

\newcommand{\mathbox}[3][\mathop]{%
  #1{\eqmakebox[#2]{$\displaystyle#3$}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat}{2}
\mathbox{A}{\sum_{\substack{j\in\mathcal{V}' \\ (i,j)\in\mathcal{A}}}}x_{ij}^E
  &\le 1,
  &\qquad& \forall i \in \mathcal{R}',\\
\mathbox{A}{\sum_{\substack{i\in\mathcal{N}_E\setminus\mathcal{N}_{342} \\ (i,j)\in\mathcal{A}}}} x_{ij}^E
  &= 0
  &\qquad& j \in \mathcal{R}_s',
\end{alignat}

\end{document}
```

[image]